# get element by index vs get with pop() Python

Tags: python, list

f.e. we have a list with 1 element

```
i = ['x']
```

**i - the list always with 1 element**

what way is more pythonic or performance:

```
element = i[0]
```

or

```
element = i.pop()
```

We dont care about that list, so if we "cut" element with pop - it is no problem for us

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or intended for a practical use? Cause if it's the latter then the most Pythonic way is to make the list with one element just be a regular string.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan That also has the added benefit of always performing better as well.

Comment: I think this depends on how you want to treat the structure, the first is like a list FIFO and the second is a stack FILO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i[0]` is more performant, since it has fewer operations to carry out.

If there's no reason to pop from the list, then why do it? That's just confusing to the next programmer looking at your code. Use `i[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most pythonic would be:

```
element, = i
```

That statement is equal to `element = i[0]`, but has the benefit of being shorter and producing an error if the array is *not* of size 1.

Comment: I don't think that's "Pythonic" at all. It's cryptic.

Comment: With python, list and tuple unpacking are very common. E.g. `x, y = point` for a list with 2 elements. This is the version of a list with 1 element.

Comment: @DaanBakker Two-element unpacking is obvious. Single-element unpacking looks like a mistake for the untrained eye